# Como puedo corregir este Breakpoint?

Tags: bootstrap, card

Hola como les va? necesito corregir estos breakpoints y no se como hacerlo, en cuestion serian a partir de 350px, 576px a 935px. lo que quiero es mantener el grid de 3 columnas y se me rompe en esos puntos. tengo que entregar esto para coderhouse y ya no me queda mucho tiempo, se agradece la colaboracion, ya que probe todo lo que se me ocurrio pero nada me esta sirviendo para poder corregirlo.
Desde ya gracias, dejo el codigo aca abajo.

```
  <h2 class="text-center">Fertilizantes</h2>
  <div class="productos row row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-2 row-cols-lg-2 g-4 mt-2">
    <div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/oro-negro-100-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$700</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/mico-pota-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Micorrizas en polvo">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Micorrizas en polvo</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$650</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big-250.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Big bud 250Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
         <h5 class="card-title">Big bud 250Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$6000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>    
  <div class="productos row row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-2  row-cols-lg-2 g-4 mt-1">
<div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rino-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Rhino skin 250ml">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Rhino skin 250ml</h5>
      <p class="card-text">$5000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/flawless-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Flawless finish 250ml">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Flawless finish 250ml</h5>
      <p class="card-text">$4500</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col" style="width: 20rem;">
  <div class="card">
    <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/candy-500.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Bud candy 500ml">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Bud candy 500ml</h5>
      <p class="card-text">$8000</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mal por tí si lo necesitas urgente ya que en la comunidad no podemos garantizar respuestas inmediatas. Faltan detalles en tu pregunta que pueden ser claves para poder responderte, sin embargo, te dejo un intento.

Comment: Hola Dj, no es MUY urgente, pero si llevo un poquito de apuro, probe lo que me dijiste pero en 355px se alarga todo y lo mismo hasta que no pasa el breakpoint de md, yo busco mantener el mismo tamaño en todas las resoluciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente hay que comprender cómo funciona el `grid` de `Bootstrap`.

Un `row` es una "fila", trata de no mezclar clases de filas y columnas en un mismo `div`.

El `grid` de `Bootstrap` consta de 12 columnas. Si quieres mantener siempre 3 items por cada `row`, debes establecer el ancho de cada ítem en 4 columnas *(12 / 3 = 4)* y no establecer `breakpoints`.

Te dejo dos opciones a falta de detalles en tu pregunta. **Ejecuta los snipets en pantalla completa y usa el inspector de código para simular el comportamiento en cualquier dispositivo.**

Con esto en mente, puedes usar:

```
<div class="productos row g-4 mt-2">
  <div class="col-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-4">...</div>
  <div class="col-4">...</div>
</div>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="text-center">Fertilizantes</h2>
  <div class="productos row g-4 mt-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/oro-negro-100-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$700</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/mico-pota-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Micorrizas en polvo">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Micorrizas en polvo</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$650</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big-250.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Big bud 250Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Big bud 250Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$6000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="productos row g-4 mt-2">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rino-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Rhino skin 250ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Rhino skin 250ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$5000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/flawless-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Flawless finish 250ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Flawless finish 250ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$4500</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/candy-500.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Bud candy 500ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Bud candy 500ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$8000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Ahora, si lo que necesitas es que cada ítem conserve siempre el mismo ancho, la solución es un poco diferente.

Puedes usar un solo `row` y dentro ubicar todos los ítem con un ancho predefinido. `Bootstrap` se encargará de mostrar la cantidad de ítems que quepan de acuerdo a la resolución de la pantalla.

```css
.definir-ancho {
  width: 20rem !important;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <h2 class="text-center">Fertilizantes</h2>
  <div class="productos row g-4 mt-2">
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/oro-negro-100-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Oro negro NAMASTE 100Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$700</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/mico-pota-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Micorrizas en polvo">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Micorrizas en polvo</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$650</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/big-250.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Big bud 250Ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Big bud 250Ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$6000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/rino-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Rhino skin 250ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Rhino skin 250ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$5000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/flawless-250-300x300.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Flawless finish 250ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Flawless finish 250ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$4500</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="definir-ancho">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="https://elalquimistagrow.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/candy-500.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="Bud candy 500ml">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Bud candy 500ml</h5>
          <p class="card-text">$8000</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hola Dj, no es MUY urgente, pero si llevo un poquito de apuro, probe lo que me dijiste pero en 355px se alarga todo y lo mismo hasta que no pasa el breakpoint de md, yo busco mantener el mismo tamaño en todas las resoluciones.

Comment: Si se te rompe es porque tal vez tienes algo en tu `CSS` que está provocando esa ruptura, **recuerda evitar la definición de `breakpoints` personalizados ya que `bootstrap` hace lo suyo con las clases predefinidas**. Veo en tu código que usas estilos en línea para definir el ancho que debe ocupar un elemento `style="width: 20rem;"` y no es recomendable si no es estrictamente obligatorio. Ejecuta el snippet de mi respuesta en pantalla completa y usa el inspector de código para ver el comportamiento responsivo del código que te dejé de ejemplo. En el snippet funciona de manera correcta.

Comment: Te reitero que si quieres mantener el mismo tamaño en todas las resoluciones, no debes hacer uso de `breakpoints`, nada de `col-md`, `col-xs`, etc, ya que esto es precisamente lo que provoca el comportamiento que para tu caso es errático. Basta con usar `col-4` para que se conserven siempre tres ítems por cada `row`

Comment: Agregué una nueva opción en la respuesta. Si aún así no es lo que buscas, edita tu regunta y trata de ser más preciso. Mientras mas detalles nos des, va ser más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: Hola DJ, acabo de probar tu solucion y lo unico que tuve que hacer para que se mantenga de la forma que yo queria fue agrerar un style="max-width= 20em;" y se soluciono, muchas gracias por tus respuestas y por tomarte el tiempo.